# Error when running a DOS command in CGI

Tags: perl, cgi, dos

I tried to run a simple copy of one file to another folder using Perl

```
system("copy template.html tmp/$id/index.html");
```

but I got the error error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

When I change it to

```
system("copy template.html tmp\\$id\\index.html");
```

The system copies another file to the `tmp\$id` foler

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), which comes with your Perl distribution.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Copy;

print copy('template.html', "tmp/$id/index.html");
```

You do not need to worry about the slashes or backslashes on Windows because the module will take care of that for you.

Note that you have to set relative paths from your current working directory, so both `template.html` as well as the dir `tmp/$id/` needs to be there. If you want to create the folders on the fly, take a look at [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

---

**Update:** Reply to comment below.

You can use this program to create your folders and copy the files with in-place substitution of the IDs.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Path qw(make_path);

my $id = 1; # edit ID here

# Create output folder
make_path("tmp/$id");
# Open the template for reading and the new file for writing
open $fh_in, '<', 'template.html' or die $!;
open $fh_out, '>', "tmp\\$id\index.html" or die $!;
# Read the template
while (<$fh_in>) {
  s/ID/$id/g;       # replace all instances of ID with $id
  print $fh_out $_; # print to new file
}
# Close both files
close $fh_out;
close $fh_in;
```

Comment: Thank for ur help!
I have a cgi file running on *nix system, but I want to run it on windows. Can you change this code to new code running on IIS windows?
...
$commands[1] = "cp template.html tmp/$id/index.html; cat tmp/$id/index.html | sed -e 's/ID/$id/g' > a;mv a tmp/$id/index.html";
system($commands);

Comment: It's only a cgi file used to convert some document types to swf and view online. I download this source code but it belongs to *nix. So hard for me to run it on windows system

Comment: It is not a CGI file, it is a Perl program. You do not need to run this through CGI/a webserver. You do have Perl on your computer, right?

Comment: That file named convert.cgi, written by Perl. But its content has a few parts only excute on *nix

Comment: It still is executed with the Perl interpreter. Anyway, see my updated answer. That will work on windows. You would run it from the command line.